# Countdown disappears when I look on mobile device

Tags: html, css

This is the html and css code I use. When I look on a mobile device or when I shrink my screen the countdown disappears, but the text not. I have added the other part of the css. Now I added all the css of the page, so the upper part is from my navbar I used in my html. I added the JS aswell. I hope someone knows how to fix this problem. Thank you in advance! I added the whole html aswell. I hope you know a solution for all the problems!

```js
(function () {
  const second = 1000,
        minute = second * 60,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24;

  let birthday = "Dec 29, 2021",
      countDown = new Date(birthday).getTime(),
      x = setInterval(function() {    

        let now = new Date().getTime(),
            distance = countDown - now;

        document.getElementById("days").innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
          document.getElementById("hours").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
          document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
          document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

        //do something later when date is reached
        if (distance < 0) {
          let headline = document.getElementById("headline"),
              countdown = document.getElementById("countdown"),
              content = document.getElementById("content");

          headline.innerText = "Bestel nu je vuurwerk!";
          countdown.style.display = "none";
          content.style.display = "block";

          clearInterval(x);
        }
        //seconds
      }, 0)
  }());
```

```css
nav{
  background: #151515;
}
nav:after{
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
nav .logo{
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #151515;
  margin: 5 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px #000000,
               0 0 10px #0a0a0a;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
  box-shadow: none;
}
nav ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}
nav ul ul ul{
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px -20px;
  width: 175px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align:center;
}
nav ul ul li a{
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 150px;
}
.show,.icon,input{
  display: none;
}
.fa-plus{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 968px) {
  nav ul{
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  nav .logo{
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .show + a, ul{
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li,nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover{
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .show{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .show:hover{
    background-color:red;
  color: white;
  border-radius:5px;
 
  }
  .icon{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25;
    right: 40px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  nav ul ul{
    top: 70px;
    border-top: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: static;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav ul ul a{
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a{
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li{
    position: static;
  }
  [id^=btn]:checked + ul{
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li{
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  span.cancel:before{
    content: '\f00d';
  }
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  background: #1b1b1b;
}
    .container {
      color: yellow;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
    }
.container li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.message {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  
  li {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    padding: .75rem;
  }
  
  li span {
    font-size: 3.375rem;
  }
}
```

```html
  

 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
      <script src="js/countdown.js"></script>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/xicon" href="images/logo-klein.png">
      <title>Knalhuis Ochten</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav>
         <div class="logo">
            <div id="myMenu">
            <div class="logo-navbar">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" height="80" /></a>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
    
         <label for="btn" class="icon">
         <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
         </label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         
            <li>
               <label for="btn-2" class="show">Assortiment</label>
               <a href="#">Assortiment</a>
               <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Knalvuurwerk</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Siervuurwerk</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kindervuurwerk</a></li>
                 
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    
     <div class="container">
  <h1 id="headline">Dagen tot vuurwerkverkoop:</h1>
  <div id="countdown">
    <ul>
      <li><span id="days"></span>dagen</li>
      <li><span id="hours"></span>uren</li>
      <li><span id="minutes"></span>minuten</li>
      <li><span id="seconds"></span>seconden</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
      <script>
         $('.icon').click(function(){
           $('span').toggleClass("cancel");
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is this all of the code? I think we're missing some.

Comment: do you need all the css of this part? or the javascript?

Comment: To provide complete and efficient help, we always advise to include all code that is being used in the process. So yes. Please include all your CSS and all JS that is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because in your media query you have this:

```
.show + a, ul{
    display: none;
  }
```

You are hiding all `ul` elements. Remove that and you'll see your numbers. You may need to keep the `.show + a`, but the `ul` is what is causing it to be hidden.

```
.show + a, nav > ul{
    display: none;
  }
```

This makes sure not every `ul` is targeted, but just the top level one in your menu.

**EDIT** In the comment you mention about your nav menu not collapsing. You can do this (or something similar since I don't have all the code):

**EDIT 2** You are seeing the `::before` font awesome elements before your numbers because all the spans are getting the `.cancel` class added. The following CSS will fix that.

```
#countdown li span.cancel::before {
    display: none;
  }
```

```js
(function() {
  const second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;

  let birthday = "Dec 29, 2021",
    countDown = new Date(birthday).getTime(),
    x = setInterval(function() {

      let now = new Date().getTime(),
        distance = countDown - now;

      document.getElementById("days").innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.getElementById("hours").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

      //do something later when date is reached
      if (distance < 0) {
        let headline = document.getElementById("headline"),
          countdown = document.getElementById("countdown"),
          content = document.getElementById("content");

        headline.innerText = "Bestel nu je vuurwerk!";
        countdown.style.display = "none";
        content.style.display = "block";

        clearInterval(x);
      }
      //seconds
    }, 0)
}());
```

```css
nav {
  background: #151515;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

nav .logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #151515;
  margin: 5 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000, 0 0 10px #0a0a0a;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  border-top: none;
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

nav ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px -20px;
  width: 175px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  line-height: 50px;
}

nav ul ul ul li {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 150px;
}

.show,
.icon,
input {
  display: none;
}

.fa-plus {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 968px) {
  nav ul {
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  nav .logo {
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li,
  nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .show {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .show+a,
  nav>ul {
    display: none;
  }
  .show:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .icon {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25;
    right: 40px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  nav ul ul {
    top: 70px;
    border-top: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: static;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav ul ul a {
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li {
    position: static;
  }
  [id^=btn]:checked+ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  span.cancel:before {
    content: '\f00d';
  }
  #countdown li span.cancel::before {
    display: none;
  }
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #1b1b1b;
}

.container {
  color: yellow;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.container li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
}

.message {
  font-size: 4rem;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  li {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    padding: .75rem;
  }
  li span {
    font-size: 3.375rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="js/countdown.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/xicon" href="images/logo-klein.png">
  <title>Knalhuis Ochten</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <div id="myMenu">
        <div class="logo-navbar">
          <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" height="80" /></a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <label for="btn" class="icon">
         <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
         </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

      <li>
        <label for="btn-2" class="show">Assortiment</label>
        <a href="#">Assortiment</a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Knalvuurwerk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Siervuurwerk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kindervuurwerk</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="headline">Dagen tot vuurwerkverkoop:</h1>
    <div id="countdown">
      <ul>
        <li><span id="days"></span>dagen</li>
        <li><span id="hours"></span>uren</li>
        <li><span id="minutes"></span>minuten</li>
        <li><span id="seconds"></span>seconden</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('.icon').click(function() {
      $('span').toggleClass("cancel");
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now my navigation bar no longer collapses

Comment: Since I don't have access to the rest of your code, you could try adding the navigation `ul` class to the selector you removed

Comment: I added the whole code now, so you have acces to all my code

Comment: Thank you, but now when I fold out the navigation bar, squares with crosses appear in front of the numbers.  Can that also be removed?

Comment: That's your font awesome icons from `span.cancel:before {content: '\f00d';}` that's used for the menu `X`. You are applying the `.cancel` class to all `spans`, so I added: `#countdown li span.cancel::before {
    display: none;
  }` This will remove the font awesome that's appearing before the numbers. If this answer solves your original question, please upvote and mark as accepted. Thanks!